# How short are "short periods of time" in Google calendar API for real?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, limit

I'm developing an application, which needs to use calendar and I've decided to try a ready-made solution - Google Calendar API. I'm making calls from my backend to google and I only store calendars' and ids in my database, everything else is stored in google. So I'm writing a proxy basically and everything is going ok, but I've bumped into this article https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en, and now I'm really worried about those "short periods of time" in exceeding limits. I haven't found more accurate numbers. Well, if those "short periods of time" are ~1h, then I'm in the trouble and I need to implement my own calendar system. Can anyone dispel my doubts? This is not a pet-project.

Comment: I don't think this information is disclosed. Anyway, about those limits, are you planning to create more than 100k events per hour, for example? Can you provide more details about your exact situation?

Comment: No, I think the only problem that may occur is with calendars. We have to make a documentation about each member of some centerS. And whenever a new member is added, I'm creating a new calendar individually for him. This event might be not that frequent. But I don't know for sure how many members can possibly be created at the one moment. For example, if its' settling in two or more centers at the same time and several admins are adding new members to db, maybe it may exceed the limit. I can imagine 60 calendars in 5 mins at worst...

Comment: While more detailed information is not available, I made some tests in order to check how restricted these limits are. I tried creating calendars periodically, with different frequencies. For example, I set up a trigger to create a calendar every minute, and got an exception `You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time` around the 40th calendar. Therefore, in this case the "short time" is actually longer than one hour, so you'd need to readjust your workflow in order to avoid these limits.

Comment: Related to the previous points, I'd suggest delaying calendar creation whenever a certain quantity of calendars have been created recently. Do you think something like this could work in your case?

Comment: @Iamblichus , "Limits for the legacy free edition of G Suite and Google Workspace trial accounts limits are lower than those stated above." Which accout type do you have? Can you try to create calendars in random periods, not in every minute? For example in 30, 44, 240 etc secs. I'm creating a calendar during member creation. Maybe, I can add "Create calendar" button on member and set my own limit over google, which will save me from their exception. But still, Idk which limit should I set) Around 20 calendars for 30 mins to be sure I think. Btw, how long couldn't you create a new calendar?

Comment: I'm thinking about adding my own limit exception. I just need to find out which is the best option..
I should have checked this before.. I'm afraid that time spent on google api is wasted and I will need to create my own calendar..

Comment: Or it would be great to extend google's limit.
"Some Calendar use limits are automatically increased when:
Your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD $100 (or equivalent), and
At least 60 days have passed since achieving that payment threshold."
I hope it also applies to the creation of calendars.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about adding RabbitMQ queue with custom delay in it, which I haven't determine yet. So on creating a member I will publish a message to RabbitMq. Message will contain information about calendar. Worker will send a request to google api and then I will store a newly created calendar ID in my database. But before worker will check whether N amount of calendars were created in Z period of time. If yes - then sleep.

Comment: I've got Enterprise account, so this shouldn't the be issue. I have tried indeed with several different periods, ranging from 5 seconds to 15 minutes. For most of these periods, the exception `You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time` started showing up around 40-45~ calendar. That was still the case for 10 minutes, but for 15 it took almost a day to start displaying the error at 85th calendar more or less, so I guess the limit is close from there.

Comment: As a workaround, I'd suggest to code your application so that it tries creating the calendar some time after receiving this error. I understand though, that these periods are very large and might not be feasible for your situation. What do you think of this?

Comment: Well, I've tested these limits too and as you said, periods are very large and this is not acceptable in my case... Actually, there is a workaround that may work: instead of creating a new calendar per member, I can create only one calendar for all members and store all their events in it. But every event will have some prop with unique value. And after that you can search through all events looking for one with that unique value with the help of "q" parameter in events.list method. Still, it will be drastically slow when the amout of events grows up.

Comment: I put off this task for a while and will leave the final decision later.

Comment: By the way, I think this question has outlived its utility, it's clear that google short periods are not that short. I also made my expirements and I've got a timeout after 25 calendars in 1 and 3 minutes intervals. I haven't tried more as it's already enough to make you think about another option. @Iamblichus, you helped me with this research, so you can summarize all you've written in the comments and I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Alright, I posted an answer summarizing all this in order to give this visibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

There's no public official information regarding the exact period this is referring to.

Nevertheless, after some testing, it seems like the `short periods` of time are longer than what your workflow would require.

#### Research:

Since the limit that is troubling you is calendar creation (from [Avoid Calendar use limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486)):

> If you create more than 60 new calendars in a short period, your calendar might go into read-only mode for several hours.

I did some tests with a Workspace account, in order to see what's the maximum rate of calendar creation that won't result in this limit being exceeded.

More specifically, I tried creating calendars periodically, with several different periods, ranging from 5 seconds to 15 minutes.

For most of these periods (from 5 seconds to 10 minutes at least), the following exception started showing up after creating 40-something calendars approximately:

> You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time

After this, no more calendars could be created for some time.

For 15-minute period, I got the error after creating around 80-something calendars, so I guess the maximum rate of creation is close from there (1 calendar created every >15 minutes). Since this rate is not disclosed, though, it could change without notice, so take this with a grain of salt.

The original poster, [GorgeousPuree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11515868/gorgeouspuree), also made some testing, with results in accordance with what I got (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771554/how-short-are-short-periods-of-time-in-google-calendar-api-for-real/67056678#comment118482050_66771554)):

> I also made my expirements and I've got a timeout after 25 calendars in 1 and 3 minutes intervals.

#### Conclusion:

In any case, the `short period` seems to be way too long for the [worst case scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771554/how-short-are-short-periods-of-time-in-google-calendar-api-for-real/67056678#comment118077697_66771554):

> 60 calendars in 5 mins